# Postgres Differences between pg_delete and "DELETE FROM ..."

Tags: php, postgresql, sql-delete

PHP: pg_delete: http://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-delete.php

and use: "Delete From . . ."

What is the difference between both sequences? Which one is more efficient? Which one is less probable to get errors?

Comment: What is `pg_delete`? I've never heard of it. Maybe that PHP function you are referring to? -- Please tag and/or clarify your question.

Comment: @pozs done! is the php function

Comment: what "both sequences" you are talking about?..

Comment: im googling and there is 2 way for ejecute a delete in postgres (using php) i can use the php function pg_delete:
$row=array("email"=>'ANY_EMAIL');
$res = pg_delete($conn, 'usuario', $row);
if ($res){...
Or using the common sintaxys for query:
$sql="DELETE FROM usuario WHERE email='ANY_EMAIL'";
$res= pg_query($conn,$sql);
if ($res){...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm only guessing here as I've never used pg_delete(), but I'd say that it constructs a `DELETE FROM...` query behind the scenes and sends it to the server.

Given this, the difference between them is that with `DELETE FROM...` you are writing the SQL by hand, while with pg_query() you're using a PHP function that does it for you (albeit at the cost of less flexibility).

Which you use will depend on what framework you're using for your database queries, and what you're most comfortable doing.

Comment: I think the same as you, but I asked because I don't know if there a more powerful reason to create the method (pg_delete), Thanks for the information!